# Xamarin Forms - Dismiss NavigationPage

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to dismiss the current page I am on when I use:

```
Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType));
```

How would I do that? I tried:

```
Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
```

But got this error:

> PopAsync is not supported globally on iOS, please use a
>   NavigationPage.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you Push the page onto the Navigation stack?
Please share that code

Comment: Where you want to go after dismiss this page? If the Detail is the `RootPage` of `NavigationPage`, you can't dismiss it.

Answer (score 0):

your `MainPage` is a `MasterDetail`, so you need to

```
var nav = ((MasterDetailPage)Application.Current.MainPage).Detail.Navigation;
nav.PopAsync();
```

Comment: Didnt work, the same view remains and is not dismissed

Comment: if you only have a single view on your navigation stack you can't dismiss it.  You can push a new page onto the stack, or completely replace the existing detail page, but you must have something there

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you are trying to dismiss the current page from you can use:

```
await Navigation.PopAsync();
```

If you're trying to dismiss the Page from outside the context of a NavigationPage, for example in a Controller class you can send the current Page's Navigation instance to the Controller.

Something like this in your Page:

```
public MyConentPage () {
    var myController = new MyController(Navigation);
}
```

Then inside your Controller:

```
public MyController (INavigation Navigation) {
    this.Navigation = Navigation;
}

public async void ClosePage () {
    await Navigation.PopAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as per your code, you are setting a Detail Page from Master Detail Page, So that you Detail Page is work like an Initial Page, you did not push or pop in to Navigation Page.

So Simple Solution is use to set Desire Page of Application or where you want to move using Application Context Like,

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new NewPage());
```

Hope this helps. if any Query than Please feel free to ask.